# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre begin y cbegin?

Tags: c++, string, begin-cbegin

Hace poco que he empezado con c++ y estoy mirando por encima los metodos de los objetos tipo string. La cosa es que aunque me cueste un poco entender el concepto de iterator no entiendo la diferencia entre begin y cbegin. He bucado lo que significan en esta página:

- begin: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/
- cbegin:https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/cbegin/?kw=string%3A%3Acbegin

Pero no me aclara nada. Os agradecería mucho si alguien pudiese explicarmelo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues es sencillo:

- `begin( )` devuelve un iterador de tipo `iterator`.
- `cbegin( )` devuelve un iterador de tipo `const_iterator`.

¿ Y que diferencia hay ? Pues muy sencillo también:

- Un `iterator` **permite modificar** aquello a lo que apunta:

  ```
  *string.begin( ) = 'A'; // Ok
  ```
- Un `const_iterator` **no permite modificar** aquello a lo que apunta:

  ```
  *string.cbegin( ) = 'A'; // Error !!
  ```

Ten en cuenta que `begin( )` devuelve una cosa u otra dependiendo del *const* del objeto:

```
const std::string test;
auto iter = test.begin( ); // <-- const_iterator

std::string test;
auto iter = test.begin( ); // <-- iterator
```

Mientras que `cbegin( )` **siempre** devuelve un `const_iterator`:

```
const std::string test;
auto iter = test.cbegin( ); // <-- const_iterator

std::string test;
auto iter = test.cbegin( ); // <-- const_iterator
```

Normalmente, pera evitar *funcionalidades no deseadas*, se usa `cbegin( )` para **garantizar** que no modificamos *sin querer* el contenido de la cadena: el compilador **genera un error** si intentamos modificar el contenido.